# Hibernate loads eagerly even after marking as lazy load

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I have the following entity relationships.

1. A User has multiple usergroups.
2. Each UserGroup has one UserRole.

The entities along with their relationships are mapped like so:

```java
public class UserGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userGroup", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private UserRole userRole;

}
```

```java
public class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups;
}
```

```java
public class UserRole {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private UserGroup userGroup;

}
```

When I execute a simple lookup query with something like this:

```java
userGroupDao.get(id)
```

I see a hibernate query, that joins usergroup, user, userRole. I want only the userGroup query, as the `user` and `userRole` are both marked with `FetchType.LAZY`. Is there an initialization problem here?

Here is the hibernate query:

```
Hibernate: /* criteria query */ select ...<list of columns>... from user_groups this_ inner join users storeduser2_ on this_.user_id=storeduser2_.user_id left outer join user_roles storeduser3_ on this_.id=storeduser3_.user_group_Id where this_.id=?


Hibernate: select ...<list of columns>... user_groups usergroupn0_ left outer join user_roles storeduser1_ on usergroupn0_.id=storeduser1_.user_group_Id where usergroupn0_.user_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies)

> With fetch="join" on a collection or single-valued association
>   mapping, you will actually avoid the second SELECT (hence making the
>   association or collection non-lazy)

Comment: You suggest changing the fetch type to select?

Comment: Yes, if you want to have select without join

Comment: But select, fetches all the references eagerly. Even though i marked them as lazy.